# Laravel app->call() doesn't pass the arguments into Controller

Tags: laravel

I am using the `app()->call()` logic to call a Controller/method, and more importantly passing arguments via the `Request` like so:

`return app()->call('\blah\blah\ControllerName@methodName',['email'=>'test@domain.com,'name'=>'zach'])`

I can see that the Controller and method is being hit, but when I `dd($request)` or `dd($request->all())` the arguments that I'm passing/sending over are not received. What am I missing in this `app()->call()` logic that is making me miss my passing of arguments?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the question.

Comment: `$request->all` is a function, try with `dd($request->all())`

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Another typo on my part. Regardless, I see no parameters passed into the Controller's method being called.

Comment: @ZachSmith Sorry, I forgot to name the request parameter

Comment: @lagbox is correct aswell, if this is an actual Illuminate\Http\Request class, you will be responsible for building it yourself before you pass it in.

Comment: That is passing arguments as in a function signature, it isn't going to add anything into a request ... the `call` method isn't specifically for controllers, it is for calling a method on anything, if you need data in the request you need to merge it into a request yourself

Comment: @lagbox If you could provide an answer to the problem that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `call` method of the Application Container is for calling any callable or class/method combination. It will gather any needed dependencies for injection and will also allow you to pass in specific arguments for the signature of the function/method. In your case you want "inputs" to exist on the Request that is passed into the method that is called, not specific parameters for the method call.

You can achieve this by merging inputs into the bound Request or cloning the Request and merging data in and passing that explicitly:

```
request()->merge([
    'email' => 'something@something.com',
    'name' => 'test',
]);

app()->call('\blah\blah\ControllerName@methodName');
```

This will inject the bound Request as it is part of the method signature. We have merged inputs into this Request so the `$request` you have in the method will have this data.

You could also clone the Request and merge in data and specifically pass this Request object:

```
$request = clone request();
$request->merge(...);

app()->call('\blah\blah\ControllerName@methodName', ['request' => $request]);
```

Comment: Amazing - both a perfect answer and proper education around the concept. Many thanks for helping me with this!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to call a method with the signature `methodName(Request $request)`. Since you want the request to be an array, and the parameters are wrapped in an array, your call needs to look like:

```
return app()->call('\blah\blah\ControllerName@methodName',[
    'request' => request()->merge(['email'=>'test@domain.com','name'=>'zach'])
]);
```

Comment: Seems that is not the case. When I `dd($request)` in the Controller method, it returns no parameters passed.

Comment: Using your updated answer, it throws this error:
`Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Api\ContactController::submit() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, array given`